# 'N' prefix for insert data to sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am  stuck for days that I search all the potential answers but nothing ....

I am trying to store greek chars values from a java api to SQLServer 2014 
but I am getting this ???????

I use the N prefix and the NsetString method but I am still getting this ???? any idea here is my code.

My app works with a button insert data from text to sqlserver...all my data stored well ecxept one the 5 column  `Περιγραφη_Υλικου` that have the greek characters

```
public void g(){

  Statement st;
      ResultSet rs;
      Connection con = getConnection();
    try {

            st = con.createStatement();
String query = "INSERT INTO ektupotiko(Αριθμος_ΔΔΥ,Ημερομηνια,Αριθμος_Ονομαστικου,Ποσοτητα,Περιγραφη_Υλικου,Μοναδα_παραλαβες,Τυλ,Δχση,Μοναδα_μετρησης) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


//rs = st.executeQuery(query);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
ArrayList<data> listdata = getListdataFromTextFile("C:\\textdata.txt");

for(int i = 0; i < listdata.size(); i ++) {
                preparedStatement.setString(1, listdata.get(i).getαριθμος_ΔΔΥ());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setString(2, listdata.get(i).getημερομηνια());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setString(3, listdata.get(i).getαριθμος_Ονομαστικου());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setString(4, listdata.get(i).getποσοτητα());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setNString(5, listdata.get(i).getπεριγραφη_Υλικου());
                                System.out.println("OK");
                preparedStatement.setString(6, listdata.get(i).getμοναδα_παραλαβες());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setString(7, listdata.get(i).getτυλ());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setString(8, listdata.get(i).getδχση());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.setString(9, listdata.get(i).getμοναδα_μετρησης());
                                System.out.println("test");
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Insert success record:" + (i + 1));
                                System.out.println(listdata.size());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static ArrayList<data> getListdataFromTextFile(String filePath) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader bReader = null;
        ArrayList<data> listResult = new ArrayList<data>();
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            bReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            //String save line get from text file
            String line = null;
            //Array save product
            String[]strdata = null;

            //Loop and get all data in text file
            while(true) {
                //Get 1 line
                line = bReader.readLine();
                //Check line get empty, exit loop 
                if(line == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    strdata = line.split(",");
                    listResult.add(new data((strdata[0]),(strdata[1]),(strdata[2]),(strdata[3]),(strdata[4]),(strdata[5]),(strdata[6]),(strdata[7]),strdata[8]));
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Read file error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //close file
            try {
                bReader.close();
                isr.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return listResult;
    }
```

Comment: what charset encoding did you use to store data in textdata.txt? And what charset encoding are you using to read this file ?

Comment: I think the problem is related to encoding issues. If you debug your code, and set breakpoint to a line of code, where you have your file data read, inspect the contents of a variable that stores data obtained from the file. I think you will see `????` or something unreadable chars there. Make sure your file is written using UTF-8 charset and specify charset upon reading your file like that `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));`

Comment: iam using utf-8 encoding

Comment: please check my comment above yours.

Comment: Make sure while storing Unicode data, the column must be of Unicode data type (nchar, nvarchar, ntext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using UTF-8 encoding in your txt file, replace the lines of your code (in `getListdataFromTextFile(String filePath)` method):

```
isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
```

to

```
isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
```

or (if you are using 1.7 JDK or newer):

```
isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Also make sure your column in the table is set to proper datatype, that supports UTF-8 chars (NCHAR, NVARCHAR, NTEXT types).

Comment: i try this bReader = new BufferedReader(isr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); but i get this error messege incobatible types charset cannot be converted to int

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your code to the line, where you read your data from your file. what data do you get? Are there correct chars or `???` ?

Comment: set breakpoint to `line = bReader.readLine();` and inspect the `line` variable contents. Are there correct characters or `???` symbols ?

Comment: I suspect your file contents are not in UTF-8 encoding. And when you read your file, the `line` variable gets incorrect data inside. Did you check this variable as I described above? Set a breakpoint to `line = bReader.readLine();`, execute this line of code, and then inspect the `line` variable contents.

Comment: give me a sec to check

Comment: It means your file contents are not in `UTF-8` encoding. How did you prepare this file?

Comment: i have some text files from access with values and i just load it to my app

Comment: In this case, instead of UTF-8, you should use encoding used to create this file. Moment please, I will check for infos.

Comment: try this encoding `iso-8859-7` instead of `utf-8` when you are initializing InputStreamReader

Comment: ok i set utf8 from not++ and i try with break point to insert the data i see the this time the right values but when i run it and try to insert the data to database i get this  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '501' to data type int.

Comment: it means you should check column number in your code and your table. You are trying to insert string value to an `int` column.

Comment: check datatype of every column you are using to insert strings. Seems that one (or more) columns, you are using to insert string values have `int` datatype set.